# Storyboard View Controller not instantiated?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to instantiate a new view controller in my storyboard with this code but it does nothing and stays on the old storyboard.

Here is the code:

```
(void)menuSelect:(id)sender {
UIButton *button = (UIButton*) sender;
switch (button.tag) {
    case 0: {
        HomeViewController *hc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Home"];
        [self presentViewController:hc animated:YES completion:nil];

        break;
    }
```

The storyboard file name is Main.Storyboard and the id for the viewController is Profile.

Here is the image of what the storyboard looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Issue

You are passing "home" as an indentifier of `HomeViewController`, while it is "profile". So what you are telling to program is: Get the `storyboard` with the name "main", instantiate the `HomeViewController` with identifier "home".

## Solution

**Change the code to:**

```
HomeViewController *hc=[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Profile"];
[self presentViewController:hc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instantiating the storyboard does not cause any View Controller to be displayed. You have to call presentViewController from another view controller.

Comment: Ok thanks, do I need to do anything special to remove the previous screen, is it pushing on top or is it just re-creating a new view, because I want to get rid of the old view if necessary.

Comment: @Lion789 it isn't replacing the ViewController that presents it, it is added to the stack. You can access the presenting ViewController through the presentingViewController property of the currently visible screen. Likewise you can access the presented ViewController through the previous ViewController through the presentedViewController property.

Comment: How would I clear the stack then so a new view is created, because I want to avoid the views staying in memory/having duplicate controllers in the stack.